# Intelij SBT Task: No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, log4j, sbt, apache-kafka

I'm trying to run a kafka program using Scala and SBT on Intelij IDEA. When running the `SBT Task` I get this warning:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig fore more info.
```

The link didn't really help me, I looked online and found out the `log4j.properties` isn't being found in my classpath. So I went into the SBT Task configurations and added the location of the file that's used in my standalone kafka directory `kafka/config/log4j.properties` and added it into the VM parameters:

```
-Xms512M
-Xmx1024M
-Xss1M
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-Dlog4j.debug=~/kafka/config/log4j.properties
```

I tried running the task again but kept getting the same error. I'm not sure how I'm suppose to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

add vm options like that ：

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:config/log4j.properties -Dkafka.logs.dir=/data/kafka-server-log
```